# Is It Possible to merge audio to video in android?

Tags: android

1. **Hi Can I add audio to Video in android(Java).**
2. List item Both are in my SD card and merge and give into mp4 format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. But it will not be so easy,
You need to learn about these api's

1. [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) to extract data/track from file.
2. [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) if you want to encode/decode
3. [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to mux it into mp4 file

You can use all three of them together if you need to or individually.
You can find some example code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-5.1.1_r1/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts).

Comment: But I am beginner to understand this code.please can you help me in details like tutorials

Comment: @AshishPatil This is **not** a tutorial site.